# СNoReverseMatch at /polls/1/ in Django 3.1

Tags: python, django, jinja2, namespace

**Всем привет!**

Сделую этой [Документации](https://django.fun/docs/django/ru/3.1/intro/tutorial04/) по созданию своего сайта на Django 3.1

Столкулся с проблемой[image: Вот картинка]Что делать?

Вот мой views.py

```
def index(request):
latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)

def detail(request, question_id):
question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})

def results(request, question_id):
question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
return render(request, 'polls/results.html', {'question': question})

def vote(request, question_id):
question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
try:
    selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
        'question': question,
        'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
    })
else:
    selected_choice.votes += 1
    selected_choice.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

Вот мой Mysite/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
]
```

Вот мой polls/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, name='index'),
path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

Вот мой detail.html

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>
{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}
<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
<input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}">
<label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br>
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote">
</form>
```

**Что не понятно спросите в комментариях, с радостью отвечу**

Comment: Попробуйте дописать `app_name = 'polls'` в вашем polls/urls.py https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls

Answer (score 0):

Окозалось всё проще простого. Добавьте это **"app_name = 'polls"** в **"polls/urls.py"**